# Select One Active Image from multiple Multiple Images

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am creating Shopping cart website in which user upload multiple images of single product. I use jquery to clone file input section to upload another image of same product at the time of adding product in database, everything work fine i successfully upload all images on my web directory and in table. Now i just facing problem to mark one image from multiple images for the use of main product Image which is used when i show all product on my application. I have Boolean column in my table for active image.

```
Table structure for table product_images
Column  Type    Null    Default
product_image_id    int(10) No  
product_id  varchar(20) No  
product_large_image_url text    No  
product_small_image_url text    No  
image_active    tinyint(1)  No
```

**How can i check which image is selected by the user to use default image so i can insert true value in table.**
 I tried with radio button in-front of of each input field, but it does not work. Any suggestion how i achieve this target ?

Comment: what exactly didn't work with radios?

Comment: what about an extra image field for cover image ??

Comment: i use radio name "activeImage" with value activeImage. when i click to add another image button jquery clone file section with radio button with same value name. so i did not find which image is selected as default because each radio value is same.

Comment: Yes. maybe cover image field is used for default product image. but my actual problem is how i can check which product image client selected for default image ?

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="active[]" value="0" class="active" />
<input type="radio" name="activeImage[]" onclick="$('.active').val(0);$(this).prev().val(1)" value="1" />
```

Now when you `dump` the data in php you have to active the image based on the index in post array like

```
[active] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
    )
```

So you know that `active[1]` contains value 1 so second image is selected by user , so make active second image in the `$_FILES` array

Hope you got my idea

Comment: how i change the value of radio value when i cloned this section ? i dont know how many images client have for one product, for tackle this problem i used jquery clone section to add as required images. I don't have predefined images section section.

Comment: you dont have to change the name of radio name will be same for all the radio buttons and when you post the form you will get `1` value against the selected radio by user and others will contain `0` or `no` just get the index of that radio in post data and update that image with index as active as explained in my answer

Comment: array in radio button is not working. i only get [0] index against 3 radio button.

Comment: if we use radio button than we should change the value of each radio button.